# Troubleshoot ASP.net WebForms download file problem

Tags: asp.net, webforms, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

In my webpage, I have a download button will write excel to response and it work previously.  But I got a problem today that browser on client (tested IE and Chrome) cannot download exported excel from ASP.net webforms suddenly without changing code and software install.

When I test in Chrome, console show that **Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet**.

I used the notepad to open the downloaded excel and the content become the my web html page.

I tried to login server and use the browser in server, the file can be download normally with correct content.

I have tried to copy the web folder to another server and iis setup, it show same behavior that the downloaded excel become html content of my page on client browser but work in server browser.

May I have any idea how to troubleshoot on this case please?

Thanks

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). All you are probably doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension. I'm guessing with `HtmlTextWriter`

Answer (score 0):

Are you facing this issue on a domain/managed network? If yes, are you the administrator of the network? If that's not the case, please give these suggestions a try:

1. If you’re using an antivirus or firewall software, make sure Chrome
   is trusted or allowed by these programs. You can also try
   temporarily disabling your antivirus or firewall to see if this
   resolves the issue.
2. Just to make sure we eliminate malware from the
   scenario, please follow the steps from this help article.

   3. Try resetting the Chrome browser to see if that helps.
   4. Also, creating a new user profile on your Chrome can be helpful.
   5. If the issue persists, download and run Chrome Canary. It is the
      cutting edge developer version of Chrome that can be installed
      alongside Stable Chrome. It's possible the problem won't exist on a
      future version.

[refrence article](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/iOmjW9QsgH4)